# POSIXct rows won't bind properly

Tags: posixct, rbind

I'm scraping data from the web to do my own little side project. My goal is to go through every single page (divided by month and year) and take each day and how many calls were made. I start with a blank data frame, and append the dates and number of calls from each month as I go on.

The problem is... when I bind the rows together, the dates turn into numbers instead. How do I fix this? (If I run the code for just one column, the dates are in the proper form.)

The issue will be in the last part of the code, but I provided the other stuff for reference.

```
#Scrapes dates from the police call map
#ex: "Tuesday, Sept. 30"
get_date <- function(url,year){
  read_html(url) %>%
    html_nodes('.bull li a') %>%      
    html_text() %>% 
    str_trim() %>%                       
    unlist() %>%
   #adds the current year to the end
    paste(year)
}

#Scrapes number of calls for each day.
#ex: "262 calls for service"
get_num_calls <- function(url){
  read_html(url) %>%
    html_nodes('.bull b') %>%      
    html_text() %>% 
    str_trim() %>%                       
    unlist()  %>%
    #Parse number is here to eliminate the "calls for service" text
    parse_number()
}

#This function converts date to proper POSIXct format.

convert <- function(date,month,year){
  if (month %in% abbr) {
    parse_date_time(date, orders = "%A, %b. %d %Y")

  } else if (month %in% full) {
    parse_date_time(date, orders = "%A, %B. %d %Y")

  } else {
    #September is not in an accepted format, so it needs to be changed.
    date <- sub("Sept.", "Sep.", date)
    parse_date_time(date, orders = "%A, %b. %d %Y")

  }
}

#years and months to cycle through the URLs
years <- as.character(2009:2018)

months <- c("jan", "feb","mar","apr", "may", "jun",
            "jul", "aug", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec")

#months that are abbreviated in the data.
abbr <- c("jan", "feb", "aug", "oct", "nov", "dec")

#months that are NOT abbreviated in the data.
full <- c("mar", "april", "may", "jun", "jul")

#url_base will have "month/year/" added to the end in the loop
url_base <- "http://projects.registerguard.com/police/eugene/"

#No matter which of these I use, it doesn't work properly.
Police <- c()

Police <- data.frame(date = as.POSIXct(date(), origin = lubridate::origin),
                     calls = integer())

for (year in years){
  for (month in months){
    url <- paste(url_base, year, '/', month, '/', sep = "")
    date <- get_date(url,year)
    date <- convert(date,month,year)
    calls <- get_num_calls(url)
    new <- cbind(date, calls)
    Police <- rbdf(Police, new)
  }
}
```